# Blower motor resistor keeps blowing

Tags: electrical, heater-blower

I have a 2006 Jeep Liberty that has had blower problems for a while. It used to be that sometimes it wouldnt blow on any setting, and then randomly come on in a few minutes after I started driving. It was a small inconvenience so I never did anything about it.

However a couple days ago it started to only blow on high. I replaced the blower motor resistor today. However, that didnt fix the issue. After pulling out the new resistor I saw that it was blown in the same spot as the one it replaced. So something is going on that blew the old resistor and immediately blew the new one. I could use some direction in where the issue could. e since I dont have much experience with the electrics in vehicles.

Comment: Seems to me if the new one blew, it was defective.

Comment: @Paulster2 So you think that's more likely than something else, even given the history of weird blower problems?

Comment: In my experience, which dates back a while, blower resistors are typically protected by one-time thermal fuses; if the heater box ever goes over-temperature (typically 70C) then the fuse opens and the blower will only work on full power, when the resistor isn’t in-circuit.  There could get a few causes: if the blower is pulling too much current, perhaps because of worn bearings or if it’s jammed, or perhaps the coolant is going over temperature, or perhaps the thermal fuse failed inappropriately.  That’s 20-year old tech though, things may be different these days.

Comment: If it's a new resistor and it blew right off the bat, you should be able to get a replacement for it under warranty.

Comment: I expect the motor is drawing too much current and blowing the resister. When working were the blowers weak? If so, new motor time.

Comment: After checking the fuses, relay, wiring, and motor I decided to just get a different brand of resistor. It works great. I learned my lesson that I should listen to Paulster2 right away! Thanks for all your help guys!